# Linux Docker Container with asp core console application

Tags: dockerfile

I had created asp core console application and within this application i had used c++ binary (dll file) reference.For my asp core application i am able to create image on linux docker but while run into the container it throws filenotfoundexception on executing C++ binary function(C++ dll unable to load or one of its dependency).Can some one help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you post dockerfile

Comment: My docker file contains.FROM microsoft/aspnetcore AS base  
   
WORKDIR /app  
COPY /bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/publish/ .  
   
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspcoreapp.dll"]

Answer (score 0):

#### Try:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore
RUN mkdir -p /app
COPY . /app
ARG files=./bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/publish
RUN mkdir -p ./appcode
COPY $files ./appcode
WORKDIR /app/appcode
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspcoreapp.dll"]
```

*Also*

Add reference `C++ Runtime`.

Under your project in **Solution Explorer**

1. Right-Click
2. Click on *References*
3. Select Add *Reference*
4. Go to Extensions
5. Check `Visual C++ Runtime Package`

Or

1. Right-click on the project in Solution
2. Explorer choose  **Add Reference**
3. Click the **Windows tab and then Extensions sub-tab**
4. Check the checkboxes for the new Extension SDKs.
5. Click OK.

Comment: Thanks for reply i am not seen any extension as u mentioned in step 4 for add reference.I am using VS 2017 for asp core application development.

Comment: OK will try with reference add but it not work with ur dockerfile structure. I am able to run with my dockerfile on windows container but not on Linux. Is it mandatory to use c++ binary build in Linux envairment?I am using windows build c++ binary

Comment: Okay, on mobile so couldn't test it, but if your original worked, Add the reference and try with your original Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

Finally I resolved the issue with using c++ binary build in Linux environment.but now I am facing the issue of I can't ping to my running container ip from my host even it is in same subnet.